# Call QAbstractTableModel setData method from QML

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am trying to make a fully generic connection between the QML `TableView` and my C++ class that subclasses the `QAbstractTableModel`. So far I am able to read the data through `data` method, as this is done internally by the `TableView` module. From what I have read over SO however, I need to call `setData` myself on the QML side. The problem is, the function header looks as follows:

```
bool setData(const QModelIndex &index,
                 const QVariant &value,
                 int role = Qt::EditRole) override;
```

In order to call it, I need the `QModelIndex`, which I dont know how to obtain on the QML side. I would appreciate a QML example.

Edit: I have worked around this issue by wrapping the `setData` as follows:

```
Q_INVOKABLE bool setData(const int row,
                             const int column,
                             const QVariant& value);

bool CVarTableModel::setData(const int row,
                             const int column,
                             const QVariant& value)
{
    return setData(index(row, column), value);
}
```

I can now call it directly on the QML side. The problem is, even though the actual `setData` is called now, the `dataChanged` signal doesnt make the QML `TableView` to update the cell... Is there anything else I am missing?

Comment: A delegate can call `setData` implicitely for its index by doing `model.roleName = value`

Comment: Thank you for answer, I think I get the idea, but do you think there is any example available?

Answer (score 1):

I can probably answer your edit. It seems like you might not be emitting `dataChanged()` signal in your `setData` function. This would explain why the view is not updated.

From QAbstractTableModel::setData() [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData):

> The dataChanged() signal should be emitted if the data was successfully set.

Also, about your original question. You could use `index` method from the qml: `model.setData(model.index(row,column), data)` to avoid overriding `setData`.

Comment: Could you show a piece of code where you call model.setData(), please? I have run into troubles with it (constantly retreiving 'undefined' value), see my post https://stackoverflow.com/q/71689954/3468283. Shortly: it works when model is defined in QML, it doesn't work when model is defined in C++/Qt. Haven't you got the same experience?