# Qt Data Models vs QML Data Models

Tags: qt, view, model, delegates, qml

Generally, there are **two distinctive ways how to define, create and attach the data model in the C++/Qt/QML model/delegate/view architecture**. Let's illustrate them on a table view example:

#1. **Inherite own C++/Qt class** from [QAbstractItemModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html) (or from its specialized children [QAbstractTableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstracttablemodel.html) for our example), define own C++/Qt/SQL/XML/JSON/etc data source/storage and re/write the necessary Qt model virtual methods to secure the upward/downward data flow. Then just initialize the [model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html#model-prop) property of QML [TableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html) when QML engine starts.

or

#2. **Define own QML model** using QML [TableModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html)/[TableModelColumn](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodelcolumn.html), fill the QML TableModel [rows](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html#rows-prop) property with some static data or append/insert/remove some dynamic data using the QML TableModel's data manipulation methods. Then just refer such a QML TableModel from QML [TableView](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-tableview.html).

**And my questions are as follows:**

Q1: Can I call the Qt QAbstractTableModel's [data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#data)(index, role) and [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#setData)(index, value, role) methods and QML TableModel's [data](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html#data-method)(index, role) and [setData](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-qmlmodels-tablemodel.html#setData-method)(index, value, role) methods from my QML JavaScript code the same way for both model definition options as described above? Hint: my impressions after extensive tests are that data()/setData() in QML JavaScript works just with QML TableModel, not for Qt QAbstractTableModel ...

Q2: If the answer for Q1 was YES (I pray-), how the C++/Qt QVariant is to be cast/converted/treated on the QML JavaScript side? The Qt QAbstractItemModel data()/setData() interchange all data as QVariants ...

**Thank you for your expertize, this is described very confusing way in the Qt/QML documentation or, better said, not described at all ...**

Comment: Did you implement the setData function in your custom QAbstractTableModel? (asking because otherwise it will have a default implementation)

Comment: @Amfasis Yes I did. Some of these method are even virtual = 0, so there is no way to not rewrite them ... And it works fine, until I won't access the QAbstractTableModel-based model from QML JavaScript ...